# Redirecting while opening the FB page from ios app. Why?

Tags: ios, facebook

I used the next code to open my facebook page from ios app :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com/pages/UNNYHOG-Entertainment/208173649242257"]];
```

And everything was fine, and it's still fine if you don't have a FB app on your device. But if you have it - you will be redirected to https://m.facebook.com/pages/UNNYHOG-Entertainment/208173649242257?id=208173649242257&_rdr

Do anyone knows why does it happening? I guess they made some changes in their app. But what should i do to fix it?

Comment: I don't understand your issue...

Comment: The question is : how can i open facebook page(not a profile, page for ex : http://www.facebook.com/pages/UNNYHOG-Entertainment/208173649242257) on iOS 6 with a last version of FB app on a device. The code that i used isn't working anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook

For a page, you will want to use `fb://profile/<page id>`

UPDATE:

If you want to only use the `fb://` url if they have facebook installed then use

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://"]]) {
    // Facebook app is installed
    fb://profile/<page id>
}
```

otherwise use the http:// url

Comment: Thank you for the response. That works, but only if i have FB app on my device. It's not working without it. Is there any universal way?

Answer (score 0):

Apple changed the canOpenURL method after iOS 9

- Solution: Add URL Schemes to the info.plist file as following

  ```
  < key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes< /key>

  < array>
  < string>fb< /string>
  < string>twitter< /string>
  < string>whatsapp< /string>

  < /array>
  ```

It's work